# php code not working, $query string not working well

Tags: php, mysqli, query-string

formatted code:

```
<?php
        require_once 'connectvars.php';

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            //set vars
            $oldpw = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['oldpw']));
            $newpw = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['newpw']));
            $retype = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['retype']));

            $query = mysqli_query($dbc, 'SELECT password from user_info WHERE password = "hash(\'SHA256\',$oldpw)" and user_id = "$SESSION[\'user_id\']"'); // this line is "not working well"

            if (strlen($newpw) < 7) {
                if (strlen($newpw) > 32 ) {
                    if (mysqli_num_row($query) == 1) {
                        if ($newpw == $retype) {
                            mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE user_info SET password = 'hash('SHA256',$newpw)'");
                            $msg = "You successfully changed your password";
                        }
                        else {
                            $msg = "Your old password doesn't match.";
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $msg = "You must enter your old password correct.";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $msg = "Your password must contain 32 characters or less.";
                }
            }
            else {
                $msg = "Your new password must contain at least 7 characters.";
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: What is this? - I just flagged. Its not clear...

Comment: try better formatting your question first....

Comment: Also, you need to write your problem NOT ONLY POST YOUR CODE.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `$query string not working well` -> wat!? explain your problem..

Comment: Iam look to my cristal ball and I cant see the question...

Comment: Make sure your submit button holds the "submit" name attribute. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: query string in combination with $_POST will not work well indeed. Use $_GET instead.

Comment: `SET password = 'hash('SHA256',$newpw)'` syntax error. Hash is a function, not a string and missing quotes for password variable. @JayBlanchard *Mornin' Sam, what's for breakfast?* - That's "my" question ;-)

Comment: Start by doing echo('$oldpw'); and see what you get. There is a difference between strings with single quotes and strings with double quotes.

Comment: *Mornin' Ralph, let's go to IHOP and get free pancakes.* That's my answer @Fred-ii- ;-)

Comment: *Mmmmm, pancakes!!!* - Let's @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard `$SESSION` gee... what's wrong with that S.G.? ;-) yeah I know. Somebody made that very same mistake. *Oops!* They got the fire down below... ♫ Too many things wrong with OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to improve your sql syntax.

```
'SELECT password 
    from user_info 
    WHERE password = "hash(\'SHA256\',$oldpw)" 
    and user_id = "$SESSION[\'user_id\']"'
```

may be corrected to

```
"SELECT password 
    from user_info 
    WHERE password = '" . hash('SHA256',$oldpw) ."' 
    and user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'"
```

to propperly escape the string. Try to correct your update statement the same way.

Comment: Too many syntax errors in OP's code and this barely covers it. Plus, you've made the same syntax error with the session's superglobal variable as the OP did.

Comment: Copied that, corrected that.and you're right. Thanx. He wanted his query to be solved and I did that, I won't waste more time here.

Comment: I'm also wondering whether or not they've also started the session. However, that piece of code I've seen circulating on Stack a lot lately. They pull Q's and A's from Stack and try to make it their own. Not a question I wanted to put an answer in, that's for sure. But... let's see what the OP has to say, *cheers*

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I change it from your way to my written way and then again back in yours and code is not working anyway. Maybe error is in diffrent part of the code.